# WDDriveService.exe: eating cpu process & excess Internet usage

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, high-cpu-usage

WDDriveService.exe is working hard, eating CPU cycles and accessing the Internet for no apparent reason.

I’m seeing this on Process Explorer (Sysinternals). (2 pics attached)

I’ve read that “wddriveservice.exe” can be malware (I.e. malware can be named “wddriveservice.exe”) and I’m puzzled to see:
Current Directory:
c:/Windows/System32

There is no wddriveservice.exe in that folder.

Also, wddriveservice.exe seems to be weirdly active with Internet access.  (See pic, below)

Apparently, I can just uninstall, but I’d like to know what’s going on here, and whether there’s some better alternative to uninstalling.

The excessive (seemingly) use of CPU time is intermittent. If I reboot the problem seems to go away, but then later it will be back. Since I generally leave my computer on 24/7(re-booting intermittently), it feels like WDDriveService.exe is waiting until I’m not watching before doing … whatever.

One site said, "The process is a service, and the service name is WDDriveService. The service provides discovery of WD Drives. The program is not visible." My WD drive is my D: drive. I don’t need some program constantly looking for it and chatting about it over the Internet.

I posted about this in the Western Digital forum, and didn't get what I need, so sending this out to StackExchange.

Thanks for any help.

P.s.  I don’t think my WDDriveService.exe concern is likely based on my rig’s hardware, but I just have the feeling that if I don’t include it, somebody will say they need it, so here ‘tis --
[Speccy]

Operating System   –    Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

CPU   –     Intel Core i7 7700 @ 3.60GHz    39 °C   –       Kaby Lake 14nm Technology

RAM   –     32.0GB

Motherboard   –     Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. Z390 AORUS ULTRA-CF (U3E1) 31 °C

Graphics   –    BenQ XL2420TX   (1920x1080@120Hz)

047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB (ZOTAC International) 45 °C

Storage   –

9314GB Western Digital WDC WD102KRYZ-01A5AB0 (SATA )    48 °C   –

931GB Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB (SATA (SSD))  32 °C   –

7452GB Seagate Backup+ Hub WH SCSI Disk Device (USB (SATA) )    49 °C

Optical Drives   –      HL-DT-ST BDDVDRW UH12NS30   –       HL-DT-ST BD-RE BH16NS40

Audio   –       Realtek High Definition Audio

Peripherals

Mouse   Razer DeathAdder V2

Printers

Fax - HP Officejet Pro 8620

HP Officejet Pro 8620

ScanSnap S1500

Smart Label Printer 450

Keyboard:  Corsair Vengeance K90        Note:  Speccy says keyboard is Razer!

[image: enter Process Explorer PrtScn 1]

[[image: enter Process Explorer PrtScn 2]

[image: enter Internet usage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> One site said, "The process is a service, and the service name is WDDriveService. The service provides discovery of WD Drives. The program is not visible."

**My experience**

I am using WD hard drives for over 10 years on Windows XP and Windows 7. They never needed anything called "WDDriveService". The operating system is able to detect them without any additional help of software from Western Digital Corporation.

Once I purchased an external drive solution containing a WD drive in an enclosure called "WD my passport Ultra" XP was permanently complaining about a missing driver although the drive was working perfectly.

Opening up a ticket with WDC did not provice additional information.

**My hint for you**

Test your WD drive on another clean machine without this dubious service.
You can run h2testw to test if your operating sytem is able to write on the whole drive and read it out thereafter.

If you succeed, remove that piece of software.
When being paranoid, you could backup the WD drive in question before.

By naked drives and put them in an enclosure of your choice when running them externally. Do not buy combos.

Consider uploading the dubious exe file to virustotal.com.

Answer (score 1):

A more concise explanation I found before I found superuser.com's answer was at:

https://www.freefixer.com/library/file/WDDriveService.exe-84727/ in the comment section

** Jason * wrote: Enables Automatic Mounting of Western Digital Hardware **Encrypted** Drive. If disabled, manual mounting is required. # 24 Feb 2015, 8:23

**If** you are ENcrypting/ENcrypted your WD HDD:

1. The simplest and cleanest method is to use the Unlock.exe. The WD HDD will remain
   unlocked until you do a "user logout" (which ends your computer user session) or
   if you reboot/shutdown the computer (It locks the HDD until next boot-up).
2. The WD Drive Manager Service (WDDriveService.exe) **MUST** be running to Set,
   Change, or Remove the HDD password.

Possibility of being **MALWARE**:

If WDDriveService.exe file is located **ANYWHERE** other than where **YOU** installed, it could be Malware. Do the steps below **FIRST** and then delete it.

```
1) **Do** a Restore Point
2) (Windows) Go to Control Panel --> Programs and features and look for **ANY** 
   WD installs. Verify the install location of the files.
3) If there is no WD installs: Use TRUSTED anti-virus/malware software (local 
   and online) and do FULL system scans.
4) Investigate whatever results the anti-virus/malware scans find
5) Allow anti-virus/malware programs to Repair/Remove selected scan results
6) Reboot computer
```

**If** you are **NOT** encrypting your WD HDD either:

```
1) Don't install the WD Security software because it is NOT needed for 
   UNencrypted WD HDD
```

OR

```
2) If you install the software, set WD Drive Manager Service to "manual" or 
   "disabled" in Services.
3) Reboot the computer.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the WD Security program if you intend to use password protection on the newer drives. After drive is unlocked you can end the service.

You can end the process by using the task manager or make a batch file to end the wddriveservice.exe service.

This is the command that I am using in my batch file to stop the service.

Taskkill /IM WDDriveService.exe /F

Google how to make windows batch files if you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

This is follow-up information, that may be helpful to anybody looking at this with the same problem.

After reading r2d3's answer, it seemed likely to me that I had gotten some malware that was using my computer for nefarious Internet activity.  Generally I run Norton protection (which, obviously, hadn't found anything wrong), so I downloaded the free Malware Bytes scanner and ran a system check.  It found a bunch of entries in my registry about something called PUP.Optional.Reimage, so I did a restore point then let Malware Bytes remove those, then re-booted.  WDDriveService.exe was still behaving badly, eating CPU cycles and Internet bandwidth.

Next, I found my Western Digital utility which I assume I installed after I installed my WD HD, probably thinking "hey, it's free, from WD who should know best how to do something good for their hardware, whatever it is doing."  So, I ran the program, and got a screen saying something like "Install a compatible hard drive" and seemed to be not recognizing my installed Western Digital HD.  Could it be that this program was just constantly searching for a WD HD, failing to find one even though it is installed and having no issues, then repeatedly reporting home to Western Digital that my computer has no Western Digital drive?

So I uninstalled the WD utility, rebooted, and voilà!  Everything is working great, and WDDriveService.exe is no longer active.  So, I'm giving R2D3 credit for the answer.  I'd have added this as a comment to his answer, but comments are limited so I couldn't have given this additional info.  I'm leaving this all here, because when I started trying to figure out this problem, I'd have loved to have found this info.

P.s.  BTW, I did buy & install my HD naked, so I assume I downloaded this useless utility from the Western Digital website.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using WD external HDs for many years, and had never considered to install any of the utilities that come with the drive. Never had any problem using the drive under Windows (XP, 2000, 7, 10).

Some time ago, I decicded to make use of the "drive encryption feature" [1]. So I needed to install *WD Security*, and this also installed the *WD Driver Service* service. And indeed, the *WD Drive Service* is using quite a bit of CPU for nothing.

To *enable* drive encryption you run *WD Security*, and set a *drive unlock password*. There is no other way, I think, to set, change, or remove the drive unlock password.

Once a password is set, there are three ways to unlock a drive when it is (re)connected to the computer:

1. Start the *WD Security* program, wait for it to detect the drive, then enter the drive unlock password to unlock the drive. This depends on the *WD Drive Service* to be started. You can close *WD security* thereafter; it doesn't have to run to work with the drive.
2. Run the program called *Unlock.exe* that you find on the *virtual CD Drive* [2] that pops up when a locked drive is connected. This program can only be used to unlock a drive (entering the password). There is no option to change or remove the password with this program.
3. Not a recommended option IMHO, but at the time you set the password (using *WD Security*), you can choose to automatically unlock the drive *at this computer*.

Options 1. needs the *WD Security* utility which in turn needs the *WD Drive Service* to be running. Option 3. needs *WD Drive Service* to be running (I guess; never tried this option). Finally, Option 2 does not depend on any of those, so you can either deinstall *WD Security*, and *WD Drive Service*, or, simply set the service to *disabled*. I recommend the latter, because it is easier to re-enable the service, than to re-install, if you have the need to change, or delete, the password.

HTH

[1] To use the *drive encryption feature* you need to set a *drive unlock password* on the drive. This, however, does *not* change the encryption state of the device! The data on the drive are *always encrypted* by the drive hardware; you can't switch that off. The difference is only whether the *encryption key* is password protected or not. There is no password set when the drive leaves the factory, but any data written to it will still be encrypted. There is *no change* to the data, when you *set*, *change*, or *remove* the unlock password. The password is only used to encrypt/decrypt the drive's internal encryption key.

[2] A drive with a *drive unlock passsword* set, is *not* popping up as an HD drive when connected (except when you use option 3 above). Instead, the drive's hardware presents a *virtual CD drive* to the computer, which you will see, despite the fact that the (HD) drive is still locked, and invisible. The main purpose of this *virtual CD drive* is to be able to give you access to some software on the (still locked) device. The *Unlock.exe* being the important one for the discussion at hand. Once unlocked the HD drive will be visible.